Pydantic V2 pass field over nested model
I am trying to validate some fields with model_validator (and field_validator). So I have a nested Model like this:
class Parent(Basemodel):
 field1: List[Child]

class Child(AnotherModel):
 field2: str

Every model has much more fields and there are even much more models, but they can be ignored now. What I want to do is, add model_validators to every model to validate some values. I can´t raise an error in the single validations, because I need all errors at the end.
So my idea was to write all errors in a list, which I can access later (I can set a error field and set it to exclude=True, so that I dont convert it with the model later on).
But how can i pass the error list to the childs ?
Or do you have a better way to solve this.
Thanks for any help :)

I don't understand your problem. You can throw JSON strings or python object structures into model_validate or model_validate_json respectively and you get all errors bundled.

@lord_haffi When I create a Model like this: res = Model(field1=abc...) etc. and i raise an error in one model_validate, all other model_validates wont run. So I get only this one error. And as second, in one model_validate, there have to be different custom errors

Just initialize using res = Parent.model_validate(my_dict) where my_dict also contains a (sub)dict at key field1 representing the Child object.

If I got your question correct, you can do the following:
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class Child(BaseModel):
    field1: int

class Parent(BaseModel):
    field1: list[Child]
    field2: str



try:
    Parent.model_validate({
        "field1": [{"field1": 1}, {"field1": "should_raise_error"}],  # Second value contains str instead of int
        "field2": 1,  # Int instead of str
    })
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e.json())  # Here will be all information about errors

Errors from your validators will also be included.
